# Software to work with excel files

Tags: 22.04, software-recommendation

I am currently using LibreOffice to read Excel/sheet files. I am trying to work with a large data file, but LibreOffice is always lagging and bugging. These files have no problem when I work with Excel on Windows.

Does anyone have any recommendations for Excel file processing software on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: MSOOXML (.xlsx) is a notoriously vague standard, and nobody outside Microsoft knows how that vagueness is handled, despite a decade of LibreOffice developers trying hard. In other words, it may be an Excel bug, deliberate or not. If so, then other Linux applications won't help -- you are experiencing vendor lock-in.

Answer (score 2):

You have some options:

1. Use ods files instead of Excel files.
2. Install MS Excel using `playonlinux`. It makes sense to install not the latest MS Office. Older ones work much better with `playonlinux`.
3. Install WPS Office. It seems to work better with MS files than Libreoffice.

Comment: Excel Online exists, use the web browser, works for I believe free for basic usage and such.

Comment: I am not sure it works well with big files.

Answer (score 1):

The first spreadsheet tool that comes to my mind is [gnumeric](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnumeric).
It's a little spartanic and you have to get used to it, but it's a nice program.

Link to the manual: [The Gnumeric Manual, version 1.12](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnumeric/stable/)

Comment: Can it open Excel files?

Comment: Yes. But I don't know if it's able to import complex spreadsheets. Importing data should work.